# Can't serialize an unsaved Parse.Object Error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to query Article table. It has a column called categories which is an array of Pointers.

```
var cat = new Category(); 
cat.id = request.categoryId;

var queryWeek = new Parse.Query(Article);
queryWeek.equalTo("categories", cat);
```

Using this, I get a :

```
Can't serialize an unsaved Parse.Object
```

Well I am not trying to save an the category object, but rather just use it for querying. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have the categoryId and not the actual Category object? Your error is that the stub you create is not regarded as an actual existing Parse.Object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's most likely that request.categoryId is undefined. That error is generated because the SDK attempts to convert the object (Category) to a pointer to create the query and fails because it doesn't have an id. Since you're explicitly setting id, it should only be undefined if the value you're setting is undefined.

Comment: You're right. I needed request.params.objectId not request.objectId...ARGHHH spent an entire on this FML. thank you!